# Android. FloatActionButton. Прямоугольный

Tags: android

хочу реализовать FAB прямоугольной формы, внутри которой текст и иконока
пробовал заменить background на кастомный, но ничего не вышло.
в интернете не нашёл ничего толковогою
буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: Попробуйте этот хак https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30715510/square-floatingactionbutton-with-android-design-library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JediBurrell уже отвечал на этот вопрос [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49260814/how-to-change-the-shape-of-floating-action-button-fab-on-android).

Ответ заключался в подключении библиотеки.

```
allprojects {
   repositories {
       ...
       maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
   }
}
```

В Manifest:

```
implementation 'com.github.JediBurrell:customFloatingActionButton:-SNAPSHOT'
```

С помощью xml создаётся нужная Вам форма (тут прямоугольник со скругленными уголками в 8dp):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="8dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
</shape>
```

И добавляется кастомная FAB с нужными параметрами (подробнее про библиотеку и полный список параметров на [GitHub](https://github.com/JediBurrell/customFloatingActionButton)):

```
<com.jediburrell.customfab.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/floating_action_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    app:fabType="custom"
    app:fabShape="@drawable/my_fab_shape"
    app:fabIcon="@drawable/ic_add_24dp"
    app:fabColor="@color/red" />
```